# Custom spatial processing function consumes a lot of memory as code runs in R

Tags: r, memory-management, raster

I have several rasters, 343 to be more exact, from [Cropscape](https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/CropScape/). I need to get the locations (centroids) and area measurements of pixels that represent potatoes and tomatoes based on the associated values in the rasters. The pixel values are 43 and 54, respectively. Cropscape provides rasters separated by year and state, except for 2016, which has the lower 48 states combined. The rasters are saved as GeoTiffs on a Google Drive and I am using Google File Stream to connect to the rasters locally.

I want to create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` from the centroids of each pixel or group of adjacent pixels for tomatoes and potatoes in all the rasters. Right now, my code will

- Subset the rasters to potatoes and tomatoes
- Change the raster subsets to polygons, one for potatoes and one for tomatoes
- Create centroids from each polygon
- Create a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` based on the centroids
- Extract the area measurement for each area of interest with `SpatialPointsDataFrame`
- Write the raster subsets and each polygon to a file.

Code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

dat_dir2 = getwd()

mepg <- make_EPSG()
ae_pr <- mepg[mepg$code == "5070", "prj4"]

# Toy raster list for use with code
# I use `list.files()` with the directories that hold 
# the rasters and use list that is generated from 
# that to read in the files to raster. My list is called
# "tiflist". Not used in the code, but mentioned later.
rmk1 <- function(x, ...) {
r1 = raster(ncol = 1000, nrow = 1000)
r1[] = sample(1:60, 1000000, replace = T)
proj4string(r1) = CRS(ae_pr)
return(r1)
}
rlis <- lapply(1:5, rmk1)

#Pixel values needed
ptto <- c(43, 54)

# My function to go through rasters for locations and area measurements.
# This code is somewhat edited to work with the demo raster list. 
# It produces the same output as what I wanted, but with the demo list.
pottom <- function(x, ...) {
# Next line is not necessary with the raster list created above. 
# temras = raster(x) 
now = format(Sys.time(), "%b%d%H%M%S")
nwnm = paste0(names(x), now)
rasmatx = match(x = x, table = ptto)
writeRaster(rasmatx, file.path( dat_dir2, paste0(nwnm,"ras")), format = "GTiff")
tempol = rasterToPolygons(rasmatx, fun = function(x) { x > 0 & x < 4}, dissolve = T)
tempol2 = disaggregate(tempol)
# for potatoes
tempol2p = tempol2[tempol2$layer == '1',]
if (nrow(tempol2p) > 0) {
    temcenp = gCentroid(tempol2p, byid = T)
    temcenpdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(temcenp, data.frame(ID = 1:length(temcenp) , temcenp))
    temcenpdf$pot_p = extract(rasmatx, temcenpdf)
    temcenpdf$areap_m = gArea(tempol2p, byid = T)
    # writeOGR(temcenpdf, dsn=file.path(dat_dir2), paste0(nwnm, "p"), driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
    }
# for tomatoes
tempol2t = tempol2[tempol2$layer == '2',]
if (nrow(tempol2t) > 0) {
    temcent = gCentroid(tempol2t, byid = T)
    temcentdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(temcent, data.frame(ID = 1:length(temcent) , temcent))
    temcentdf$tom_t = extract(rasmatx, temcentdf)
    temcentdf$areat_m = gArea(tempol2t, byid = T)
    writeOGR(temcentdf, dsn=file.path(dat_dir2), paste0(nwnm,"t"), driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
    }
}

lapply(rlis, pottom)
```

I know I should provide some toy data and I created some, but I don't know if they exactly recreate my problem, which follows.

Besides my wonky code, which seems to work, I have a bigger problem. A lot of memory is used when this code runs. The tiflist can only get through the first 4 files of the list and by then RAM, which is 16 GB on my laptop, is completely consumed. I'm pretty sure it's the connections to the Google Drive, since the cache for the drive stream is at least 8 GB. I guess each raster is staying open after being connected to in the Google Drive? I don't know how to confirm that.

I think I need to get the function to clear out all of the objects that are created, e.g. temras, rasmatx, tempol, etc., after processing each raster, but I'm not sure how to do that. I did try adding `rm(temras ...)` to the end of the function, but when I did that, there was no output at all from the function after 10 minutes and by then, I've usually got the first 3 rasters processed.

27/Oct EDIT after comments from RobertHijmans. It seems that the states with large geographic extents are causing problems with `rasterToPolygons()`. I edited the code from the way it works for me locally to work with the demo data I included, since RobertHijmans pointed out it wasn't functional. So I hope this is now reproducible.

Comment: Your `rm` call currently does nothing: at the end of the function, these objects leave the scope anyway. If you need to manually free memory you’ll also need to call `gc()` after that. This should *generally* not be necessary, though.

Comment: You could run `profvis::profvis()` to get a better idea of what is consuming memory and/or time.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I appreciate your comment. I did not add gc() to the code. I checked local drive and found most of the memory was being taken up by R. There were a couple of RTemp folders that were pretty big. I guess they were left over from the other times I tried my code and just killed it. So R was eating up the memory. I went back through the code line-by-line with California, since that was the usual stopping point. It seems that [rasterToPolygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382238/r-rastertopolygon-works-slow-then-stop-working) is the problem. That and CA's size.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't use `profvis` before and it was difficult for me to figure out what was going on, especially while it hung with the underlying process.

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly answering my own question, but here it is: the [rasterToPolygons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382238/r-rastertopolygon-works-slow-then-stop-working) function is notoriously slow. I was unaware of this issue. I waited 30 minutes before killing the process with no result in one of my attempts. It works on the conditions I require for rasters for Alabama and Arkansas for example, but not California.

A submitted solution, which I am in the process of testing, comes from this [GitHub repo](https://gist.github.com/Pakillo/c6b076eceb0ef5a70e3b). The test is ongoing at 12 minutes, so I don't know if it works for an object as large as California. I don't want to copy and paste someone else's code in an answer to my own question.

One of the comments suggested using `profvis`, but I couldn't really figure out the output. And it hung with the process too.

Comment: seems to me that the question is whether you need to make polygons at all --- but if that is what you want to do, `terra::as.polygons` is much faster

Comment: @RobertHijmans You're probably right. But my convoluted model of creating polygons only to create the points that will be used to extract the info I need from the raster is the only way I picture. If you have a better suggestion, I'm all ears. This question is still without an accepted answer. ;) Thank you for suggesting `terra::as.polygons`. I'll check it out forthwith...

Comment: @RobertHijmans  Ahhh... a replacement for `raster`. Okay, let's go!

Comment: It is not that asy to suggest an alternative because it is not that clear what you are trying to accomplish and you have not provided a minimal reproducible example.  But to compute area, you could use the raster data, for the centroid you could use points.